# How do you programmatically detect dual booting (particularly Linux) from within Windows?

Tags: windows, scripting, system-administration

My dad is looking for ways to automate checking the settings of a Windows server for giving it a standards compliance grade. He needs to know if more than one OS is installed, but wants to avoid taking down the server at all costs. Is there any technique within Windows (XP and newer) for programmatically ascertaining whether a machine has multiple OSs installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you consider "an installed OS".

At the very least you'd have to scan all partitions (including the ones Windows's limited filesystem support can't recognize) for filesystems and then see if they "look" like another OS. If you need to know if the alternate OS is bootable as well, you'll have to scan for boot loaders and their configuration as well.

By the way, what difference does it make if there's another OS installed on the computer?

Comment: My dad works for a hospital chain and they are not supposed to keep sensitive data on multiply-bootable computers as a precaution. Thanks!!

Comment: @abadidea: I don't see how that works as a "precaution". If the user has enough access to the computer to boot another OS (get past BIOS and into the bootloader), they'll likely have enough access to stick in a thumb drive with another OS as well. Or hell, open the thing up and reset the BIOS if they need to.

Comment: @matti-virkkunen I agree with you that it doesn't really accomplish all that much but them's the rules and they're basically impossible to change.

Comment: I think you're best off just telling them that any technical solution would be "expensive" to code. Ah the pointy haired bosses of the world who don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely reliably. You could attempt to access the MBR and the partition table and sniff for evidence of the competition if you can persuade Windows to let you open the other partitions as raw devices. It would be a heap of work.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing a checksum of the bootloader and comparing it against a known-good list of Windows OS bootloaders on the HDs?